# Implicit dependencies do not work with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a little problem with one of my projects. In my workspace I have my main project and a lot of projects for static libraries. When I build from Xcode, everything works fine, but with xcodebuild, one of my project is not built, it seems that implicit dependencies do not work.k. Maybe I did something wrong with my configuration. So there it is.

My scheme configuration:
[image]

My QAPreferences.a information:
[image]

My target settings:
[image]

From Xcode, if I build with buildAppTarget in debug for iphoneos, it works.

From xcodebuild, with command below, QAPreferences project is not built.

```
xcodebuild -workspace myProject.xcworkspace -scheme buildApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos
```

It worked before, but I recently added QAPreferences, and it does work since this moment. Maybe the problem comes from QAPreferences project...

Regards,
Quentin

Comment: Why not make them explicit dependencies then?

Comment: I tried, but does not work neither. :(

Comment: Wait are you talking about dependencies, or linked libraries?

Comment: I think it is a dependencie, I have a QAPreferences project in my project that build a libQAPreferences.a. But I found what is the difference but this project and the others.

Answer (score 3):

So I finally found why the QAPreferences was not build through xcodebuild but I still do not understand the reason. In fact QAPreferences 'Build Archive Architecture Only' was set to YES, I just set it to NO and now it works!

Comment: Saved me a ton of time sir.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but forgot to specify the `-workspace` argument to `xcodebuild`, which led to it seeming like the implicit dependencies weren't working correctly. I realize this wasn't the issue with the original question, but for people having issues with implicit dependencies, this could be helpful.

Comment: Indeed, after I "upgraded" an old project which had Referenced Projects to be a Workspace instead, my build script needs to reflect this upgrade and build from the workspace instead.  Sometimes we miss the obvious.  Thank you  :)